# Order data within group by that has 2 different columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with a discussion board where there will be a certain topic and the user can comment or upvote another comment. Each comment can also be replied by another user and will recieve notifications.

#### My notification table

- `notification_id` is  the user_id of the logged in user that will receive the notification
- `notification_from` is the user_id of the one who commented or like the users post.
- `notification_topic` is the id of the topic plus the type of notification that will distinguish if it is a comment or an upvote
- `notification_comment` is the comment_id in the topic

```
+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+---------+--------+
| notification_id | notification_pic        | notification_name | notification_title                   | notification_user_id | notification_date | notification_from | notification_topic | notification_comment | type    | status |
+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+---------+--------+
|               1 | 32_1380182434_thumb.jpg | Sheena Salazar    | Chrysler files papers for share sale |                    2 | 1380188338        | 32                | 83_upvote          | 1                    | upvote  | read   |
|               2 | 32_1380182434_thumb.jpg | Sheena Salazar    | Chrysler files papers for share sale |                    2 | 1380188342        | 32                | 83_comment         | 1                    | comment | read   |
|               3 | 93_1379990163_thumb.jpg | vhon samson       | Chrysler files papers for share sale |                    2 | 1380188505        | 93                | 83_upvote          | 1                    | upvote  | read   |
|               4 | 93_1379990163_thumb.jpg | vhon samson       | Chrysler files papers for share sale |                    2 | 1380188509        | 93                | 83_comment         | 1                    | comment | read   |
|               5 | 93_1379990163_thumb.jpg | vhon samson       | Chrysler files papers for share sale |                    0 | 1380246975        | 93                | 83_comment         | 1                    | comment | unread |
|               6 | 93_1379990163_thumb.jpg | vhon samson       | Toyota and Nissan in vehicle recall  |                    2 | 1380247149        | 93                | 225_comment        | 3                    | comment | read   |
|               7 | default.gif             | kath aguilar      | Chrysler files papers for share sale |                    2 | 1380253584        | 7                 | 83_comment         | 1                    | comment | read   |
|               8 | default.gif             | kath aguilar      | Chrysler files papers for share sale |                   93 | 1380253870        | 7                 | 83_comment         | 2                    | comment | unread |
+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+---------+--------+
```

#### My query

This is how I query and group my table:

```sql
SELECT *, COUNT(notification_topic) AS topic_count
    FROM tbl_notification
    WHERE notification_user_id =  '{$_SESSION['id']}'
    GROUP BY notification_topic
    ORDER BY notification_date DESC 
    LIMIT 8
```

This is the result of the query:

```
+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+---------+--------+-------------+
| notification_id | notification_pic        | notification_name | notification_title                   | notification_user_id | notification_date | notification_from | notification_topic | notification_comment | type    | status | topic_count |
+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+---------+--------+-------------+
|               6 | 93_1379990163_thumb.jpg | vhon samson       | Toyota and Nissan in vehicle recall  |                    2 | 1380247149        | 93                | 225_comment        | 3                    | comment | read   |           1 |
|               2 | 32_1380182434_thumb.jpg | Sheena Salazar    | Chrysler files papers for share sale |                    2 | 1380188342        | 32                | 83_comment         | 1                    | comment | read   |           3 |
|               1 | 32_1380182434_thumb.jpg | Sheena Salazar    | Chrysler files papers for share sale |                    2 | 1380188338        | 32                | 83_upvote          | 1                    | upvote  | read   |           2 |
+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+---------+--------+-------------+
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aad545/1/0).

#### What I need

I need to get the count so that I can come up with a notification like on facebook, like this:

[image]

My main problem is I can't `ORDER` it by `notification_date` before the `GROUP BY` because I need to isolate each `notification_comment` by its `notification_topic`. I want the latest user that commented or like each topic to be displayed. How will I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly then you want the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), which can be obtained by selecting the identifying criteria in the group and then joining back to your table:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     tbl_notification NATURAL JOIN (
           SELECT   notification_topic,
                    notification_user_id,
                    MAX(notification_date) AS notification_date,
                    COUNT(*)               AS topic_count
           FROM     tbl_notification
           WHERE    notification_user_id = 2
           GROUP BY notification_topic,
                    notification_user_id
         ) AS t
ORDER BY notification_date DESC 
LIMIT    8
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aad545/6/0).

Comment: Amazing! I never heard the "NATURAL JOIN" in mysql. Thanks! This is all i needed! Thank you!